# Splitting a unicode string within a generic list

Tags: python, string, unicode, split

So my data looks like this:

```
data = {"technology1": [
       [
       20, 0.02,
      u'10.00,106.10,107.00,107.00,0.45',
      u'24.00,-47.15,-49.50,-51.00,0.12',
      u'11.00,0.35,0.00,0.00,0.92',
      u'0.00',0.04,0.16, u'0.223196881092', u'f',0.02,
     ], 
      [
       100, 0.02,
  u'10.00,106.10,107.00,107.00,0.45',
  u'24.00,-47.15,-49.50,-51.00,0.12',
  u'11.00,0.35,0.00,0.00,0.92', u'0.00', 0.04,
  0.16, u'0.223196881092',  u'f', 0.01
   ] ... ],

       "technology2": ...}
```

As you can see, it is a dictionary, with each key accessing a list of lists, all with the same format. Each "inner" list contains a mix of ints, floats. There are also unicode strings, some with single values in them, some with a set of 5 numbers within the unicode string.

What I want:

To make an array for each technology. In each array, the rows will be the "outer" list of the above, and the columns the different elements of the "inner list". The unicode ideally needs to be converted to strings (as I know how to work with them better), and the sets of 5 numbers in the unicode strings need to be expanded to be an element each.

I.e. Array for technology1

```
20, 0.02, 10.00, 106.10, ... "f", 0.02
100, 0.02, ...            "f", 0.01
```

Attempt so Far:

```
for tech in data:

    features = data[tech] # i.e. grab technologyn
    for row in features:
        for i in row[2:5]: # 2 til 5 defines the instance which are sets of 5
            #print i,"\n"
            i = str(i)
            i = i.split(',')
```

This does not work, and when I look at features after code execution, it's exactly the same!

This isn't an attempt at a complete solution, as it obviously won't convert all the unicode types to strings, but this is a stepping stone.
I also tried to used a list comprehension as so:

```
for row in features:
    [i.split(',') for i in row if (type(i)==unicode and "," in i)]
```

Comment: If those unicode strings only contain ASCII characters, Python 2 will automatically encode them to ASCII for you whenever you mix operations on them with bytestring objects. I'd not worry about the `u` prefixes in that case.

Comment: `i` is a separate reference to an object. Assigning new results to that name will not update any other references, including the indices in the original list. `i = i.split(',')` creates a new list and assigns the reference to `i`. Whatever `i` referenced before is not going to be affected.

Comment: So your expected output for the first row? How are numeric columns recognised?

Comment: So you *also* need to convert those strings to floats, right?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new list object for each row, then *replace* the original list values:

```
def row_to_values(row):
    values = []
    for col in row:
        if isinstance(col, unicode) and col != u'f':
            # split and convert all entries to float
            values += (float(v) for v in col.split(','))
        else:
            values.append(col)
    return values

for value in data.values():
    value[:] = [row_to_values(row) for row in value]
```

The `value[:] = ...` assignment tells Python to replace all indices contained *in* the list object with a new set of objects. Since each `value` is an outer list in your `data` dictionary this replaces all the sub-lists with expanded rows.

Demo on your partial sample data:

```
>>> data = {"technology1": [
...        [
...        20, 0.02,
...       u'10.00,106.10,107.00,107.00,0.45',
...       u'24.00,-47.15,-49.50,-51.00,0.12',
...       u'11.00,0.35,0.00,0.00,0.92',
...       u'0.00',0.04,0.16, u'0.223196881092', u'f',0.02,
...      ],
...       [
...        100, 0.02,
...   u'10.00,106.10,107.00,107.00,0.45',
...   u'24.00,-47.15,-49.50,-51.00,0.12',
...   u'11.00,0.35,0.00,0.00,0.92', u'0.00', 0.04,
...   0.16, u'0.223196881092',  u'f', 0.01
...    ]],
... }
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data["technology1"][0])
[20,
 0.02,
 u'10.00,106.10,107.00,107.00,0.45',
 u'24.00,-47.15,-49.50,-51.00,0.12',
 u'11.00,0.35,0.00,0.00,0.92',
 u'0.00',
 0.04,
 0.16,
 u'0.223196881092',
 u'f',
 0.02]
>>> pprint(row_to_values(data["technology1"][0]))
[20,
 0.02,
 10.0,
 106.1,
 107.0,
 107.0,
 0.45,
 24.0,
 -47.15,
 -49.5,
 -51.0,
 0.12,
 11.0,
 0.35,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.92,
 0.0,
 0.04,
 0.16,
 0.223196881092,
 u'f',
 0.02]
```

So one row can be expanded to consist of all the float values in the strings with a function call returning the new list object.

Using that function to replace all rows in all dictionary values:

```
>>> for value in data.values():
...     value[:] = [row_to_values(row) for row in value]
...
```

and we can see that the first row we looked at before has been updated:

```
>>> pprint(data["technology1"][0])
[20,
 0.02,
 10.0,
 106.1,
 107.0,
 107.0,
 0.45,
 24.0,
 -47.15,
 -49.5,
 -51.0,
 0.12,
 11.0,
 0.35,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.92,
 0.0,
 0.04,
 0.16,
 0.223196881092,
 u'f',
 0.02]
```

As has the rest of the dictionary:

```
>>> pprint(data)
{'technology1': [[20,
                  0.02,
                  10.0,
                  106.1,
                  107.0,
                  107.0,
                  0.45,
                  24.0,
                  -47.15,
                  -49.5,
                  -51.0,
                  0.12,
                  11.0,
                  0.35,
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  0.92,
                  0.0,
                  0.04,
                  0.16,
                  0.223196881092,
                  u'f',
                  0.02],
                 [100,
                  0.02,
                  10.0,
                  106.1,
                  107.0,
                  107.0,
                  0.45,
                  24.0,
                  -47.15,
                  -49.5,
                  -51.0,
                  0.12,
                  11.0,
                  0.35,
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  0.92,
                  0.0,
                  0.04,
                  0.16,
                  0.223196881092,
                  u'f',
                  0.01]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose list-comprehension-heavy solution. In case the conversions does not exactly match task goals, feel free to comment below. Explanations are inlined as comments in code snippet:

```
def split_or_wrap(item):
    """Split if str, wrap if number."""
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item.split(',')
    elif isinstance(item, int) or isinstance(item, float):
        return [item]
    else:
        raise Exception("Unxpected item.")


def try_to_convert(item):
    """Try to convert string into in, then into float or leave as is"""
    try:
        return int(item)
    except:
        try:
            return float(item)
        except:
            return item


# initial list contains values' side of data dictionary
initial_list = [item for item in data.values()]

# flattened list contains list of lists where each list
# corresponds to single technology
flattened_list = [[item 
                   for tech_list in outer_list
                   for item in tech_list] 
                  for outer_list in initial_list]

# deconstructed list takes unicode strings and splits them.
# To make resulting elements consistently nested into lists
# we take single elements and put also in a list.
# This enables us to treat all lists similarly on final flattening step.
deconstructed_list = [[split_or_wrap(tech_item)
                       for tech_item in tech_list] 
                      for tech_list in flattened_list]

# final list contains array of arrays where each array
# contains single numbers (if they are convertible).
# This is done through flattening the so called item-wrapper
# lists into the list corresponding to a particular technology.
final_list = [[try_to_convert(item)
               for item_wrapper in tech_list
               for item in item_wrapper]
             for tech_list in deconstructed_list]


print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[[20, 0, 10.0, 106.1, 107.0, 107.0, 0.45, 24.0, -47.15, -49.5, -51.0, 0.12, 11.0, 0.35, 0.0, 0.0, 0.92, 0.0, 0, 0, 0.223196881092, 'f', 0, 100, 0, 10.0, 106.1, 107.0, 107.0, 0.45, 24.0, -47.15, -49.5, -51.0, 0.12, 11.0, 0.35, 0.0, 0.0, 0.92, 0.0, 0, 0, '0.223196881092f', 0], 
 [100, 0, 10.0, 106.1, 107.0, 107.0, 0.45]]
```